# PHP array loop, accessing by numeric index

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have two arrays at the bottom, I'm looking to output their values by a numeric index. Seems so simple yet I cannot get it to work for the life of me. I'm nesting these into a few other foreach loops.

```
 $x = $ppro_model->orderedByDate($val->ProdCode);
                          $xx = $ppro_model->receivedByDate($val->ProdCode);
                          $ordQty = arrayDateBuilder($x, 'ordQUANTITY', $daterange);
                          $recQty = arrayDateBuilder($xx, 'recQUANTITY', $daterange);
```

$ordQty and $recQty will ALWAYS have the same amount of elements.
So ideally I would like to be able to do the following:

```
 for($i = 0; $i <= count($ordQty); $i++){
                        echo "<td>";
                        echo $ordQty['recQUANTITY'][$i];
                        echo $recQty['ordQUANTITY'][$i];
                        echo "<td>";
                    }
```

but I'm definitely doing something wrong. Any advice would be appreciated.

I also tried:

```
  echo $ordQty[$i];
```

to not avail.

```
array (size=7)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'DATE' => string '20141110' (length=8)
      'ordQUANTITY' => string '55.00' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'DATE' => string '20141111' (length=8)
      'ordQUANTITY' => string '80.00' (length=5)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'DATE' => string '20141112' (length=8)
      'ordQUANTITY' => string '70.00' (length=5)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'DATE' => string '20141113' (length=8)
      'ordQUANTITY' => string '135.00' (length=6)
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'DATE' => string '20141114' (length=8)
      'ordQUANTITY' => string '70.00' (length=5)
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      'DATE' => string '20141115' (length=8)
      'ordQUANTITY' => string '120.00' (length=6)
  6 => 
    array (size=2)
      'DATE' => string '20141116' (length=8)
      'ordQUANTITY' => string '0' (length=1)
```

then one like:

```
array (size=7)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'DATE' => string '20141110' (length=8)
      'recQUANTITY' => string '0' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'DATE' => string '20141111' (length=8)
      'recQUANTITY' => string '0' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'DATE' => string '20141112' (length=8)
      'recQUANTITY' => string '0' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'DATE' => string '20141113' (length=8)
      'recQUANTITY' => string '0' (length=1)
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'DATE' => string '20141114' (length=8)
      'recQUANTITY' => string '0' (length=1)
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      'DATE' => string '20141115' (length=8)
      'recQUANTITY' => string '0' (length=1)
  6 => 
    array (size=2)
      'DATE' => string '20141116' (length=8)
      'recQUANTITY' => string '0' (length=1)
```

Comment: echo $ordQty[$i]['recQUANTITY']; ?

Comment: @Hobbes: Post as an answer.

Comment: as per Barmar's answer, use `foreach` to make your life easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had your array expressions backward, it should be `$ordQty[$i]['ordQUANTITY']`. Also, your loop condition was wrong, it should be `$i < count($ordQty)`, not `<=`, since array indexes go from `0` to `count-1`.

It can be simplified a bit using `foreach`.

```
foreach ($ordQty as $i => $ordElt) {
    echo "<td>";
    echo $ordElt['ordQUANTITY'];
    echo $recQty[$i]['recQUANTITY'];
    echo "<td>";
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, simple stupid things get over looked sometimes.